# How do i store an unknown data type in java(it will be known when the user types it in (int/double))

Tags: java

I know this is probably a little low, but i'm just wondering , say i want to prompt the user for an input, a number which according to what i'm trying to model could either be an integer or a double ,how do i accept this input , say
a = myScanner.next??()

Comment: Well in what way are you going to know which kind of number the user is entering? It's not really clear exactly what you're asking about - how to call the right method, or what to do with the value afterwards.

Comment: Casting to "Object" and storing in an object?

Comment: A `double` can't be (accurately) represented as an `int` but an `int` can be represented as a `double`.

Comment: I would call `nextDouble` and work with `double` until it is specified as `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Scanner` class' `hasNext` methods.
That is, if `myScanner.hasNextInt()` returns true, then the user has input an int. If `myScanner.hasNextDouble()` returns true, then the user has input a double. From the documentation, any `hasNext` method does not skip any input when called.

```
int a = 0; double b = 0;
if(scan.hasNextInt()){
    a = scan.nextInt();
}else if (scan.hasNextDouble()){
    b = scan.nextDouble();
}
```